# Can't connect from Java to ms-sql server using jdk 1.8.0_231

Tags: java, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect to ms-sql database from java using `jdk1.8.0_231` and fail with this exception:

```
The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this?
When I use 1.8.0_111, the connection is successful but I must use the 231 version since in my project I need to connect to other database with encrypted password that is not supported by the 111 version.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you only change the JRE and JDK, or also switch to a different computer?

Comment: Yeah, check (ping) the server as @Taschi is indicating. Firewall, route, network.

Comment: only JDK, same computer and same environment